# shrinking stl string to a capacity of less than 15 characters

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Consider std::string, and the capacity

```
 std::string aString = "12345678901234567890";
 std::cout << aString.capacity() << std::endl; // capacity is 20
 aString.clear();
 std::cout << "size: " << aString.size() << std::endl;
 std::cout << aString.capacity() << std::endl; // capacity is 20
 aString.shrink_to_fit();
 std::cout << aString.capacity() << std::endl; // capacity is 15?
 std::string newString;
 std::cout << newString.capacity() << std::endl; // capacity is 15?
```

Is 15 characters the minimum capacity? Is there any way to shrink it to the actual size of the string?

Comment: I'm not sure you'd get any benefit whatsoever considering the major implementations today all use short string optimization.

Comment: Everything you've observed here is implementation-defined behavior, and vary from compiler to compiler. As such, this is of absolutely no useful purpose, whatsoever. This particular compiler's implementation likely involves so-called "short string optimization" that allows strings up to 15 characters to be stored as part of `std::string` itself, rather than dynamically allocated. But, that's an internal compiler implementation behavior that, as I said, you cannot rely on.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's what I was worried about. Fwiw, it's gcc 4.8, -std=gnu++11

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `’\n’` ends a line.

Comment: I am unable to see anything here that needs to be "worried about". This is a fairly routine implementation of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations of `std::string` use the "short string optimization" which uses space in the string itself, rather than dynamically allocated memory, to store the contents of small strings.  So, you can't shrink the string because that memory is part of the string itself.

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible in **msvc2017 basic_string** implementation since constructing an empty `std::string` would allocate at least 15 chars.

More details:
`std::string.capacity()` returns `_Myres`, which represents current length of allocated storage

```
// Implementation of std::string.capacity()
_NODISCARD size_type capacity() const noexcept
    {   // return current length of allocated storage
    return (this->_Get_data()._Myres);
    }

// Construct an empty string would call _Tidy_init() method
    basic_string() _NOEXCEPT_COND(is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<_Alty>)
        : _Mybase()
        {   // construct empty string
        _Tidy_init();
        }
// Moreover, initialize _Myres by enum constant value
void _Tidy_init()
    {   // initialize basic_string data members
    auto& _My_data = this->_Get_data();
    _My_data._Mysize = 0;
    _My_data._Myres = this->_BUF_SIZE - 1;
    // the _Traits::assign is last so the codegen doesn't think the char
    // write can alias this
    _Traits::assign(_My_data._Bx._Buf[0], _Elem());
    }
// _BUF_SIZE stands for literal number 16 (std::cout<<std::string::_BUF_SIZE;)
enum
    {   // length of internal buffer, [1, 16]
    _BUF_SIZE = 16 / sizeof (value_type) < 1 ? 1
        : 16 / sizeof (value_type)};
```